# Docker windows loading kernel modules

Tags: windows, docker, module, kernel, squashfs

I'm running Docker for Windows (similar effect described below is observable on MacOSX)
I have a Docker Container in which a program tries to access a squashfs image. To access squashfs the kernel has to be either complied with loopdevice support statically or load the relevant kernel module. 
When I try to mount the image or setup the loop device the kernel that's shared between docker containers cannot find the loopdevice module.
I could possibly use unsquashfs tool but the squashfs image is used for a reason: squashfs has a very decent property: it allows unlimited number of files and inodes - if I try to to unpack the image I quickly hit the inode limit of the images.
Is Moby Linux kernel which is shipped with docker a statically compiled kernel? What volume to mount to have access to its /lib/modules? `lsmod` run in a privileged container lists no loaded modules. Trying to `modprobe loop` yields the following error message:

`root@6e1b23cc65e5:/# modprobe loop
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.8-moby/modules.dep.bin'`