# How to access the moby linux kernel modules in Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, moby

Docker for Windows 1.13.1 is bundled with Linux kernel moby:

`root@6e1b23cc65e5:/# uname -a
Linux 6e1b23cc65e5 4.9.8-moby #1 SMP Wed Feb 8 09:56:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

But when I try to load a module the command line yields:

`root@6e1b23cc65e5:/# modprobe loop
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.8-moby/modules.dep.bin'`

When you run containers on a linux host apparently the containers and the host share the same kernel so you are able to load them before a container is launched.

Maybe there's an image with the kernel /lib/modules/4.9.8-moby? So using a privileged container I could load linux modules?

Comment: Docker for Windows is not currently designed to be user-modifiable in the way that you propose. Can I ask what module you'd like to load and what your use-case is? Maybe it's something that we can support.

Comment: I'm trying to get access to a squashfs image. I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867655/docker-windows-loading-kernel-modules earlier

Comment: With docker's release of the Moby project, you could theoretically build your own version with different kernel settings. I don't think they have kernel module support yet, but recall there being lots of discussion around the topic.

Comment: Thanks very much for this suggestion. I'll definitely look it however I'm very disappointed that the kernel cannot be modified easily for the standard docker distros. Users using a linux host are really in a priviledged position here because they can change the kernel functionality easily.